# How do I return function after getting the value in http call?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have something like this

```
getFieldsRemote(){

  let fields: FormfieldBase<any>[] = [];
   this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getFields').subscribe(
    data =>{
       // code to push objects from data to fields variable declared above
           }

    }

  )
    return fields;
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that whenever I call this `getFieldsRemote()` method from my other components I get a blank array.
 I understand this is happening because subscribe method is asynchronous therefore it is working in the background and the control reaches the return statement before code section inside subscribe is executed. However I need this function to somehow return the data when the subscribe method has completed. Subscribing to the data in the component side is not an option. Please tell me what's the solution here.

Comment: *Subscribing to the data in the component side is not an option*: too bad, because that's exactly what the solution is. Your method should return an Observable<FormfieldBase<any>[]>, and the component (or its view, via the async pipe) should subscribe to it. Why do you rule out the proper thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have to worry about subscriptions you can simply turn into a promise and use async/await

```
async getFieldsRemote(){

  let fields: FormfieldBase<any>[] = [];
  const data = await this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getFields').toPromise()
  // do what you want with the data
  return fields
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I can't thank you enough. This solved my problem. Also I appreciate the prompt response.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to avoid subscribing from the component(s), you could mark the method async and await the response from the http call.

```
async getFieldsRemoteAsync(){
  let fields = await this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getFields').toPromise();
  return fields;
}
```

Note that if you do this, the consumer method will also need to be marked as async and the call needs to be awaited:

```
await getFieldsRemoteAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the consumer method also has to be marked as async. That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

If subscribing is not an option and you want to do it the Observable way then this problem can't be solved. You need to subscribe in the component to get the data, but it is better to use `async` pipe in the template. In that way, the subscription is cleaned up by Angular when the component is cleaned up.

### Solution

The `getFieldsRemote` method should return an `Observable<FormfieldBase<any>>[]` by doing so:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

getFieldsRemote(): Observable<FormfieldBase<any>>[] {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getFields');
}
```

Also, try to avoid the `any` typing and write an interface. Then in your component, assign the result of `getFieldsRemote()` to a property `fields`.

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  fields: Observable<FormfieldBase<any>>;

  constructor(private service: ExampleService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fields = this.service.getFieldsRemote();
  }
}
```

In your template then do:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <!-- Do something with your field -->
</div>
```

### Additional information

If the problem is that your `getFieldsRemote` method would be called by several components and you want to share the result (not doing multiple http calls), then look into the `share` or `shareReplay` rxjs operators.

For example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

getFieldsRemote(): Observable<FormfieldBase<any>>[] {
   return this.http
     .get('http://localhost:8080/api/getFields')
     .pipe(share());
}
```

But you might need to elaborate more on the why of *"Subscribing to the data in the component side is not an option."* as it is a definite code smell.

Answer (score 0):

You must subscribe to your method inside component:

If apiservice has a method be like this:

```
public getCustomer(customer: Customer){
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiURL}/customers/`,customer);
}
```

Consume it inside component like this:

```
this.apiService.getCustomer(customer).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log("get a customer", res);
});
```

Note: createCustomer in apiservice return an observable